# Ramsey's infinite and finite and compactness theorem

Tags: logic

Ramsey's infinite theorem : for all $c,d>0$ and for all function $f: [\mathbb{N}]^d \to c$ there is an infinite subset $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $f|[A]^d$ is constant function.

Ramsey's finite theorem : for all $c,d>0$ for all $k>0$ there is $N>0$ such that for every function $f: [N]^d \to c$ there is subset $A \subset N$ such that $f|[A]^d$ is constant and $|A| \geq k$.

Prove Ramsey's finite theorem  using Ramsey's infinite theorem and compactness theorem ?

I don't have a clue on how to start solving this, please help

Comment: Assume that the finite Ramsey theorem is false ...

Comment: @AsafKaragila O.k. , and then what ?, could you please put out simple steps to follow ?

Comment: Children do not learn how to write if someone else writes for them all the time.

Comment: If you're accustomed to a formulation of compactness of the form "finitary information implies infinitary information", for example "finite satisfiability implies satisfiability", then it would seem useful to work with the contrapositive of the desired Ramsey implication. That is, assume a counterexample to the finite Ramsey theorem and use compactness to produce a counterexample to the infinite version.